# Can't validate security stamp in asp.net core

Tags: concurrency, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, logout

Im using asp.net core Identity. What I'm trying to do is when a user login again using the same credentials the previous login should be logged out. This is my code:

Login Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginDto loginDto){ 
       if(!modelState.IsValid)
          return View(logindto);
     var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginDto.username);
             if (user.Session==false){

               user.Session=true;
                await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
             
                user.LoginDate = DateTime.Now;
                _context.SaveChanges();

}
```

Identity service extension

```
public static class IdentityServiceExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
        services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>().AddRoles<Role>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>().AddSignInManager<CustomSignInManager<AppUser>>();

            services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options=>{
              options.ValidationInterval=TimeSpan.Zero;
       });

        //implement cookie
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(opt =>
        {
            opt.Cookie.Name = "cClient";
            opt.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            opt.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login/";
            opt.LogoutPath = "/Auth/Logout/";
            opt.ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            
            opt.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/Handle/401";
            
        });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(opt =>
        {
            opt.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict;
            opt.ConsentCookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc(opt =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            opt.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(opt =>
        {
            opt.AddPolicy("HoOnly", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HoOnly()));
        });

        return services;
    }
}
```

}

Start up

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplicationServices(_configuration);
        services.AddIdentityServices(_configuration);  
        services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });                                                      
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //security middleware
        app.UseXContentTypeOptions();
        app.UseReferrerPolicy(opt => opt.NoReferrer());
        app.UseXXssProtection(opt => opt.EnabledWithBlockMode());
        app.UseXfo(opt => opt.Deny());
        app.UseCsp(opt => opt
            .BlockAllMixedContent()
            .StyleSources(s => s.Self().UnsafeInline())
            .FontSources(s => s.Self())
            .FormActions(s => s.Self())
            .FrameAncestors(s => s.Self())
            // .ImageSources(s => s.Self().CustomSources("https://www.w3.org/2000/svg"))
            // .ScriptSources(s => s.UnsafeInline().Self().UnsafeEval().CustomSources("sha256-NkjQhhVxID3uKTZQylIN4GOkRMSDKaVyPr5YZsv+cTU="))
        );

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000");
                await next.Invoke();
            });
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/Handle/{0}");

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAntiXssMiddleware();

        //cookie
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        //auth
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

}

But it does not sign out/logout the user. What am I doing wrong?

[Start up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E2Zd.png)

[Identity service extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhRS3.png)

[Login Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv9Lz.png)

Comment: Hi @Jimy, when I test your code and you can see the cookie disapears for the next request. So what you want is not like that?

Comment: Hi @Rena will it invalidate the previous login/user or will it also logout the same user that is currently logged in? but this is weird because when I'm running this code the cookie did not disappear that's why even if the security stamp is updated the user is still logged in.

Comment: It is similar to what I want because removing the cookie will logout the user but in case nothing is happening even if the security stamp is updated. I hope you can help po

Comment: Hi @Jimy, it seems you need share more code to us. e.g. your whole Startup.cs.

Comment: Hi @Rena finished editing the post, please see the whole codes above. Thank you